# Underlying implementation of Boehm-Demers-Weiser garbage collector

Tags: c, garbage-collection

I have read the FAQ and some introductions on the official website of the **[Boehm-Demers-Weiser garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/)**, and also read the page on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector#Design). But I am still curious to know how the Boehm GC implement the garbage collection.

1. Does it fork the other thread and continuous running the memory check loop until the program exits?
2. How the [mark-and-sweep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection) algorithm work by tracing the pointers located in sections in programs like `bss`, `data`, etc? What is the root set in the picture that showed in the page of the wikipedia (click "mark-and-sweep" to link to the page)?